# Networking with AT&T

Tags: networking

Just installed Ubuntu and currently have no network or internet on that computer, Not sure how to set it up. I have the AT&T NVG510 modem/router. Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this router is wireless then the ID and password (or the Key) are written on the back of it. If this is an Ethernet then all you have to do connect your computer to it via a network cable.
Ubuntu by default is set so it will take an IP address automatically form the router (I dont know about that particular moel but most router have DHCP built in which gives IP addresses).
Ubuntu usually comes up and ask if you want to join a wireless network and shows a list pick your router enter the info and in few sec, you will have Internet.